# Stop service which is an inner class from an activity

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to do a screencast like app. I take screenshots every few seconds. I send a Broadcast to the currently displayed `Activity` and `onReceive` I call method to take screenshot. The `Service` is an inner class of a class I call from Activity, to start the service.

I start the service which sends broadcast in the `onCreate` of activity and stop it `onPause`I want to know which Activity is currently displayed, so I send a string to constructor of the class with the `Service` which is used to know which Activity to send the broadcast to.

I just want to know how to stop a service which is an innerclass, from an activity.

The innerclass with Service:

```
public class InnerServiceClass {

static String activityName;

InnerServiceClass(String activityName){
    this.activityName = activityName;

} // UNREGISTER RECEIVER
public static class SShotService extends Service{
    Intent intent;
    private static final String TAG = "BroadcastService";
    public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.websmithing.broadcasttest.displayevent";
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();
    ArrayList objects = new ArrayList();
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "serv", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
        handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000);
    }
    private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            DisplayLoggingInfo();
            handler.postDelayed(this, 2000); // 5 seconds
        }
    };
    private void DisplayLoggingInfo() {
        Log.d(TAG, "entered DisplayLoggingInfo");
        intent.putExtra("extra", activityName);
        sendBroadcast(intent);


    }
}
}
```

The `onReceive` in activity:

```
private BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent1) {
        if(intent1.getExtras().getString("extra").equals(activityName))
        {
            takeScreenshot();
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: @greywolf82..posted the code

Comment: @greywolf82. can you understand what im trying to do? will it work

Comment: @greywolf82..i'm new to programming..can you tell me how else to do